# Opencv tutorials and examples including c++

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

Hi I am running the 3rd tutorial of Opencv 2.4.3 on my Samsung galaxy 2, and it freezes immediately when pressing 'play' in eclipse.
the simple samples with no ndk and c-code works fine.

I attached the LogCat of Eclipse:

```
01-20 18:33:46.464: I/OCVSample::Activity(17468): Instantiated new class org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native
01-20 18:33:46.464: I/OCVSample::Activity(17468): called onCreate
01-20 18:33:46.474: D/CameraBridge(17468): Attr count: 3
01-20 18:33:46.474: D/JavaCameraView(17468): Java camera view ctor
01-20 18:33:46.574: D/CameraBridge(17468): call surfaceChanged event
01-20 18:33:46.599: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Service connection created
01-20 18:33:46.599: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Trying to get library path
01-20 18:33:46.954: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Trying to get library list
01-20 18:33:47.209: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Library list: ""
01-20 18:33:47.209: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): First attempt to load libs
01-20 18:33:47.209: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Trying to init OpenCV libs
01-20 18:33:47.209: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Trying to load library /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so
01-20 18:33:47.209: D/dalvikvm(17468): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x4158b5d0
01-20 18:33:47.224: D/dalvikvm(17468): Added shared lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x4158b5d0
01-20 18:33:47.224: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): OpenCV libs init was ok!
01-20 18:33:47.224: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): First attempt to load libs is OK
01-20 18:33:47.224: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Init finished with status 0
01-20 18:33:47.224: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Unbind from service
01-20 18:33:47.224: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17468): Calling using callback
01-20 18:33:47.229: I/OCVSample::Activity(17468): OpenCV loaded successfully
01-20 18:33:47.229: D/AndroidRuntime(17468): Shutting down VM
01-20 18:33:47.229: W/dalvikvm(17468): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c871f8)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_sample: findLibrary returned null
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native$1.onManagerConnected(Sample3Native.java:33)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:314)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-20 18:33:47.229: E/AndroidRuntime(17468):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 18:36:41.642: I/Process(17468): Sending signal. PID: 17468 SIG: 9
01-20 18:36:42.092: I/OCVSample::Activity(17774): Instantiated new class org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native
01-20 18:36:42.092: I/OCVSample::Activity(17774): called onCreate
01-20 18:36:42.112: D/CameraBridge(17774): Attr count: 3
01-20 18:36:42.112: D/JavaCameraView(17774): Java camera view ctor
01-20 18:36:42.132: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Service connection created
01-20 18:36:42.132: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Trying to get library path
01-20 18:36:42.377: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Trying to get library list
01-20 18:36:42.612: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Library list: ""
01-20 18:36:42.612: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): First attempt to load libs
01-20 18:36:42.612: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Trying to init OpenCV libs
01-20 18:36:42.612: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Trying to load library /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so
01-20 18:36:42.612: D/dalvikvm(17774): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x4158d068
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/dalvikvm(17774): Added shared lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x4158d068
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): OpenCV libs init was ok!
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): First attempt to load libs is OK
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Init finished with status 0
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Unbind from service
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(17774): Calling using callback
01-20 18:36:42.637: I/OCVSample::Activity(17774): OpenCV loaded successfully
01-20 18:36:42.637: D/AndroidRuntime(17774): Shutting down VM
01-20 18:36:42.637: W/dalvikvm(17774): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c871f8)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_sample: findLibrary returned null
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native$1.onManagerConnected(Sample3Native.java:33)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:314)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-20 18:36:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 18:37:08.612: I/Process(17774): Sending signal. PID: 17774 SIG: 9
01-20 18:37:20.797: I/OCVSample::Activity(18138): Instantiated new class org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native
01-20 18:37:20.802: I/OCVSample::Activity(18138): called onCreate
01-20 18:37:20.812: D/CameraBridge(18138): Attr count: 3
01-20 18:37:20.812: D/JavaCameraView(18138): Java camera view ctor
01-20 18:37:20.827: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Service connection created
01-20 18:37:20.832: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Trying to get library path
01-20 18:37:21.057: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Trying to get library list
01-20 18:37:21.327: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Library list: ""
01-20 18:37:21.327: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): First attempt to load libs
01-20 18:37:21.327: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Trying to init OpenCV libs
01-20 18:37:21.327: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Trying to load library /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so
01-20 18:37:21.327: D/dalvikvm(18138): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x4158e028
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/dalvikvm(18138): Added shared lib /data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x4158e028
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): OpenCV libs init was ok!
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): First attempt to load libs is OK
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Init finished with status 0
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Unbind from service
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(18138): Calling using callback
01-20 18:37:21.342: I/OCVSample::Activity(18138): OpenCV loaded successfully
01-20 18:37:21.342: D/AndroidRuntime(18138): Shutting down VM
01-20 18:37:21.342: W/dalvikvm(18138): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c871f8)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_sample: findLibrary returned null
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native$1.onManagerConnected(Sample3Native.java:33)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:314)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-20 18:37:21.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18138):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: there are thousands similar problems in the web - google it.

Comment: i'm after hours of checking solutions in google, if you have a link to a good explanation, i will be more than happy to try it.

Comment: Google search phrase: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_sample: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: i tried the solution mentioned in the first result on google, but i were unable to add the code that given there because the original system.loadlibrary is in Switch/Case and you can't write "static" in the middle of a "case".

Comment: You don't need to add `static` actually (do you know what is static block in java actually?). The main idea of that answer is loading two libraries (first is `opencv_java`, second is your native lib) and not one as in default example.

Comment: i added the line loading the opencv_java library, but now i got "Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null", i think that it happened because i don't know where exactly to put "libopencv_java.so"

Comment: does your apk contains these libs?

Comment: no he doesn't. how can i add libs to the apk file? and thanks for the help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you check folder `libs/armeabi-xxx/`? Also try to debug that line to know the **exact problem**.

Comment: there isn't "libs" folder in the project.

Comment: First of all, I told you to check this folder in APK file (you can open it using any zip tool). But anyway from your post I know the solution - your should do `ndk-build` (native build) before building project in Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but can you detail about how to do the ndk-build?